# Passing code as function argument in Javascript and that code uses variable defined in the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I have following javascript code. I am trying to achieve a hide/display generic function on change in select form field. Lets take an example. Suppose I have a select field where values are "none", "auth", "other" and if user selects "auth" then display another form field. I may have such situation many places in the form for different select fields. Hence I have written this function below `profile_field_toggler`

```
function escapeJquerySelectorStr(str) {
  if (str) {
    return str.replace(/([ #;?&,.+*~\':"!^$[\]()=>|\/@])/g,'\\$1');      
  }
  return str;
}

function profile_field_toggler (cotroller_id, reciever_id, block_code) {
  parsed_controller_id = "#"+escapeJquerySelectorStr(cotroller_id);
  parsed_reciever_id = "#"+escapeJquerySelectorStr(reciever_id);
  selected = jQuery(parsed_controller_id + " option:selected").val();
  if(block_code()) {
    jQuery(parsed_reciever_id).removeClass("hide");
  } else {
    jQuery(parsed_reciever_id).addClass("hide");
  }
}
```

Here I make call to the generic function i.e `profile_field_toggler`. Last argument of the generic function accepts conditional code, so I am passing it in the call below `selected == "auth"` . BUT `selected` has no scope in this call hence it will not work (as I want to refer the selected variable in the generic function). So how can I solve this problem? Please note, I must want to keep the condition such as `selected == "auth"` or `selected != "xyz"` or `selected == "undefined"` in the caller only, because they may vary.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   profile_field_toggler("base[remove_option]", "general_passwordassword_block", function() {selected == "auth"});
});
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: You're sure you're not complicating this a tad too much ?

Comment: @adeneo, thanks for pitching in. I may agree to you. But that is not a point here. What I put here is just a dummy code, while actual implementation is based on similar problem. So lets find the solution of the problem :)

Comment: Keep your *condition* as a string and then call `eval()` on it? I assume that at the time of call `selected` is in a calling function scope.

Answer (score 0):

A closure can only access variables in its own scope, but definitely will not (and can not) have any knowledge of the scope of the function that eventually calls it.

In this particular example - perhaps "block_code" should take selected as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

It looks weird, but I found the solution. It seems you can pass `selected` in the call from caller only and even if it is defined in the generic function, it will work. Check this out. I just added `return` so that condition can be evaluated. and it worked. I tested with all different conditions and it is working ..sweet, but weird.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  profile_field_toggler("base[remove_option]", "general_passwordassword_block", function() {return(selected == "auth")});
});
```

Comment: It's not weird. It works because you're using all global variables, which in general is not the best of ideas.